# Changes to custom module are not recognised by jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a custom module polynomial.py, when I make changes to it they are not effective, and there is no change to the output. Here is the code:

```
p = [[1,3],[-4,7]]
q = [[2,9],[1,4],[2,3]]
p_plus_q = polynomial.add(p,q)
print(p_plus_q)
```

I tried to solve this issue using this code, but it doesn't work.

```
import polynomial
import importlib
polynomial = importlib.reload(polynomial)
```

Restarting the kernel also does nothing.

Usually after waiting a while the changes I make work, but this happens at random. I am very confused, any help is appreciated!

Comment: _when I make changes to it they are not effective_ Did you SAVE your changes?

Comment: Also, the call to `reload()` will execute within milliseconds of the first import.  Surely the module did not change in that short time.